# How to pass parameters on "Press Enter" jquery php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am workig with jquery and php,I have input type textbox and i want to execute function by "onclick" OR "Press Enter button"
But problem is ...i am trying to pass parameters (via data attributes) to anoter function then nothing works,Here is my code

```
 <input type="text" id="txt" class="feed_in_input fi1" name="">
```

Here is my script

```
$('.fi1').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
      handleClickAndEnter(e);
    }
  });

$('.feed_reply_smiley').on('click', function(e) {
    handleClickAndEnter(e)
});


function handleClickAndEnter(e) 
    {
        var txt_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('button', 'txt');
        var vals = $('#'+txt_id).val();
        var pst=$(this).data('pst');
        var cst=$(this).data('cst');
        var pidd=$(this).data('pidd');
        alert(txt_id + vals);

        .....ajax code
        ....
    }
```

If i just use "onclick" function then all parameters passing properly but i want to pass parameters in both condition ("onclick" or "Press enter button")
How can i do this ? Where i am wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: `feed_reply_smiley` must be referring to a different element which doesn't have those data attributes (because your textbox doesn't have that class)

Comment: @ADyson: Please write correct code so i can check at my side

Comment: If you want handleClickAndEnter to be used by different elements then you can't use `this` within it. Instead, select the element specifically to get its attributes

Comment: P.s. which element actually holds these data attributes? You haven't shown them here

Comment: try to replace $(this) with $(e.target)

Comment: @R4ncid: Can you please write exact code ?

Comment: const $this = $(e.target) ad than replace $(this) with $this in the handleClickAndEnter function